# Change codemirror render function in show-hint.js

Tags: render, codemirror

I would like to modify rendering hints in code mirror using 
 **render: fn(Element, self, data)**  in show-hint.js with some id and replace those IDs in hint text inserted while reading value from codemirror using getValue()

Sample hint:

displayText : test

text: %%test%%

And the text should be mapped with some id in the background, it should be retrieved while getting value from the codemirror when the text in the codemirror contains special character '%%'

Could anyone please, help me to achieve this.